# Compare two metrics where only one label is different in prometheus

Tags: prometheus, monitoring

Here is the situation and what I'm trying to achieve:

- On two distinct servers we have one file per host that gets updated once per day for multiple hosts. We monitor when this file gets updated and based on a certain amount of time spent since the last modification date, we raise an alert.
- This is what the alert looks like: `time() - node_textfile_mtime_seconds{instance=~"server1|server2"} > 194400` (where one label is file="filename.prom"). This works well to raise an alert PER server, but if I want to raise an alert when the last modification was done more than 194400 seconds ago on both servers for the same file, then this is where I get stuck.

I looked up how to use logical AND and plenty of other things but couldn't find a proper way of doing it. The next best thing I've found is this, but it's two alerts when I'd like to only have one:

`(time() - node_textfile_mtime_seconds{instance="server2"} > 194400 unless (time() - node_textfile_mtime_seconds{instance="server1"}) < 194400)`

and

`(time() - node_textfile_mtime_seconds{instance="server1"} > 194400 unless (time() - node_textfile_mtime_seconds{instance="server2"}) < 194400)`

Do you know of a better way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After many more other expressions tested, I think I've finally found the answer to my own problem. If anyone is facing the same issue, here's my expression:

```
count by (file) (time() - node_textfile_mtime_seconds{instance=~"server1|server2"} > 194400) == 2
```

Basically we know that for the same file, there is 2 versions: one on server1 and the other on server2, so we check if the expression is true for both files and the alert gets raised when that's the case.